# Getting ArtifactId and Version in Spring Boot Starter

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, manifest

I am currently developing a Spring Boot Starter which will host a Restful web service with some meta-data about the running application.

I am having difficulties extracting my artifactId and versionId from my mainfest file.  I believe my issue is that the autoconfiguration classes are being loaded before the main Test application so the manifest is not yet available to be discovered.  I am not sure if my logic here is correct of if I am approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

I originally followed the following [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter) for setup.

This gave me 3 separate projects

`Generic Spring Services with no context
AutoConfiguration project for these services
Spring Boot starter`

I paired the starter with a test project as an end result.

Currently maven is being used with Spring Boot to generate a manifest file.

`Implementation-Title: MyExampleProjectWithCustomStarter
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: mcf
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.coolCompany
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.5.4.RELEASE
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.coolcompany.SpringBootExampleApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
Implementation-URL: http://someurl`

However, when I attempt to locate the manifest file for the Example project from my generic service package I cannot find the file.

```
  private String getApplicationVersion(String applicationName, List<Attributes> manifests) {
    String unknownVersion = "0.0.0-UNKNOWN";

    for (Attributes attr : manifests) {
      String title = attr.getValue(IMPL_TITLE);
      String version = attr.getValue(IMPL_VERSION);
      if (version != null) {
        if (applicationName.equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
          return title + ' ' + version;
        }
      }
    }
    log.warn(
        "Could not find MANIFEST file with '" + applicationName + "' as Implementation-Title."
        + " Meta-API will return buildVersion '" + unknownVersion + "'.");

    return applicationName + ' ' + unknownVersion;
  }

  private List<Attributes> loadManifestFiles() {
    List<Attributes> manifests = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      Enumeration<URL> resources =
          Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
      while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL url = resources.nextElement();
        try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
          manifests.add(new Manifest(is).getMainAttributes());
          System.out.println("Manifest size:" + manifests.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
          log.error("Failed to read manifest from " + url, e);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Failed to get manifest resources", e);
    }
    return manifests;
  }
```

Current manifest Implementation-Titles:

`Spring Boot Web Starter
    Spring Boot Starter
    Spring Boot
    Spring Boot AutoConfigure
    Spring Boot Logging Starter
    null
    null
    jcl-over-slf4j
    null
    log4j-over-slf4j
    null
    Spring Boot Tomcat Starter
    Apache Tomcat
    Apache Tomcat
    Apache Tomcat
    hibernate-validator
    null
    JBoss Logging 3
    ClassMate
    jackson-databind
    Jackson-annotations
    Jackson-core
    spring-web
    spring-aop
    spring-beans
    spring-context
    spring-webmvc
    spring-expression
    Spring Boot Actuator Starter
    Spring Boot Actuator
    null
    ** MyCustom-spring-boot-starter
    ** MyGenericSpringService
    null
    null
    null
    Metrics Core
    JVM Integration for Metrics
    null
    null
    Jackson datatype: JSR310
    ** MyService-spring-boot-autoconfigure
    slf4j-api
    spring-core`

** Missing MyExampleProjectWithCustomStarter

count of manifest records: 44

Comment: Can you share the error logs? Also how are running the project? In editor or cmd line?

Comment: I removed editor from the picture right now I am simply maven installing and  using java -jar.  Currently there is no error other than a manifest missing when I retrieve all the manifests

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After a lot of effort, I found a surprisingly simple answer. This is how spring-boot-actuator gets the information.

The Spring Boot Maven plugin comes equipped with a build-info goal.  As long as this goal is triggered in the main project Spring has a BuildProperties class you can wire in for the information.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

You can access the properties in your starter like:

```
@Autowired
BuildProperties buildProperties;

...
buildProperties.getArtifact();
buildProperties.getVersion();
```

You can even specify additional properties from the plugin. See the plugin documentation for more details:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/build-info-mojo.html

Unfortunately I never quite got to fully understand why I could not access the correct manifest, but this should help anyone else trying to solve this problem.

Comment: for spring-boot projects, this is lot easier compared to other approaches (such as buildnumber-maven-plugin and git-commit-id plugins)

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is completely correct. Just for others finding this question in case you are using Gradle instead of Maven:

Generating build info is as simple as adding this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '<your-boot-version>.RELEASE'
}

// ...    

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

And if you want to pass custom properties:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            additional = [
                'property.name': 'property value',
                'other.property': 'different.value'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then the usage in Java code is the same using `BuildProperties`. You can find more info about the plugin in [this guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/).

Comment: is there a code need to add to get this build info? I have a war file which deploy in a standalone tomcat. But I cannot find any /info there.

Comment: Essentially you just need to @Autowire BuildProperties object in spring and then you can access these values. More info here: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-version/